# Menu items gets deleted automatically #wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm adding some  sub items to menu .On saving the changes, i notice that my last items in menu gets deleted automatically.could somebody know what to do in order to avoid this .

Comment: Edit .htaccess file which is located in html folder  by including
 "php_value max_input_vars 2000"
full path: /var/www/html/
  



Also made changes in php.ini file
max_input_vars = 3000;
if no php.ini file exists then we need to create php.ini file in wp-admin folder
and add this  line 
max_input_vars = 3000;
now everything working fine 
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you have reached a limit of addition of more menu items in wordpress menu.

To solve this you just need to modify your php.ini file which is in wp-admin folder. Just need to increase limit my increasing "max_input_var" through php.ini file.

Just place `max_input_vars=5000;` to your php.ini file to get rid of this menu item limit.

For more explanation, check here : http://www.wptricks24.com/how-to-increase-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress

Comment: i'm using amazon webservices as my hosting server and i cannot find any php.ini file in wp-admin .could you please tell me exact path to locate this file

Comment: Just go to this link, you will find the exact explanation :  http://www.wptricks24.com/how-to-increase-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress
It is mentioned here that if you don't have php.ini in your wp-admin folder than you can create it.